# react-pagination style disturb other component

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using the react pagination and add it on my ticket component and also import the style. Its work fine but disturb the header menu.

Here my react-paginate.css

```js
.container{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.page{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.disabled{
    cursor: not-allowed;
    
}

.active{
    border: 2px solid #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.previous{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.break{
    padding: 10px;
}

.next{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This react-paginate.css file I just import in my ticket.js

```js
import '../../../assets/css/react-Paginate.css'
```

I want that only when I import that css file any other component they not affect other component. Any idea how this work in any good way

Answer (score 2):

Hello I think your css style in your ticket component is affecting to another component in your project. This is happing because due to writing style conflict.
If your check following points so it might be worked

- Avoid to write the globe style.
- Always used the prefix name to avoid css conflict.
- Always used the unique class name to reduce the css name conflict.